# How to compress a video file to a specific size using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, video, ffmpeg, compression, video-compression

I need to compress files to fit 5mb cap. 
It doesn't matter which compression methods are used, I just need the easiest way of compressing file to a certain size in JavaScript.

Comment: It should go without saying that there definitely exist files that cannot be compressed to some arbitrary size. Also video is *already* compressed. I doubt it's possible to get better than 5% to 10% smaller.

Comment: Messenger is able to compress video from 10mb to 5mb. This is exactly what I'm looking for

Comment: Generally "compression" refers to reducing the storage size without altering the source.

Comment: You meant lossless compression. I clearly need lossy compression, because 5mb is very small

Comment: Right. Getting an hour-long video down to 5 megabytes is a lot of loss.

Comment: What do you mean by “in JavaScript” does that mean in a browser, or in node.js?

Comment: node.js -----------------

Comment: Does anyone foud the solution?

Comment: This might be too late but try using ffmpeg. It's used to handle video file encodings